# Поиск PersistentArrayMap по части ключей

Tags: clojure

Есть файл со строками вида `"Word1 Word2 100"`, по ним создаются элементы:

```
(defn file-lines
  [file-name]
  (line-seq (io/reader file-name)))


(defn create-element [line]
  (let [[a b c] (str/split line #"\s+")]
    {:first a :second b :number c}))


(defn elements []
  (->>
    (file-lines "resources/file")
    (map #(create-element %))))
```

И строка "Word1 Word2". Как можно проверить, что такой элемент содержится в `elements` (т.е. игнорируя `:number`)? И если содержится вернуть найденный элемент, иначе этот элемент с `:number` 0? Думал проводить сравнение с select-keys, но тогда теряется `:number`.

Comment: Pro tip: `(let [[a b c] (str/split line #"\s+")] {:first a :second b :number c})` См. [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring).

Comment: Ну, я намеренно ужимал код, чтобы в комментарий поместиться, не забывайте думать и сами. Использовать осмысленные имена бывает полезно :)

Comment: @D-side, я понимаю, но вопрос обобщенный тут особо не придумаешь. Есть предположение решить так: отфильтровать список по совпадению, и если он не пуст, то вернуть этот элемент, иначе создать необходимый. Будет ли для этого правильным фильтр: `(filter #(and (= (:first %) first-word) (= (:second %) second-word)))` ?

Comment: Это сработает. "Правильным" можно сделать и потом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Думал проводить сравнение с `select-keys`, но тогда теряется `:number`.

Это смотря где делать `select-keys`. Если делать это **в предикате для `filter`** для выкидывания неподходящих мапов, то вычисленные им мапы вы нигде больше не увидите, т. к. они персистентные и на исходные значения не влияют:

```
(let [src [{:first "a" :second "b" :number 42}
           {:first "c" :second "d" :number 7}
           {:first "e" :second "f" :number 10}]
      pred (fn [element] (-> element (select-keys [:first :second])
                                     (= {:first "c" :second "d"})))]
  (filter pred src)) ; => ({:first "c", :second "d", :number 7})
```

Таких элементов может потенциально быть много, поэтому возвращается **список** мапов.

---

А можно пойти вообще другим путём и сделать структуру данных другого вида, мап с ключами `[слово1 слово2]` и значениями `число`. [С помощью `get`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get) найти (или не найти) нужное значение проще простого:

```
(let [src {["a" "b"] 42
           ["c" "d"] 7
           ["e" "f"] 10}]
  (println (get src ["c" "d"] 0)) ; 7
  (println (get src ["y" "z"] 0))) ; 0
```

А ещё [с помощью `juxt`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt) можно сделать функцию, которая выдаст вектор значений по нужным вам ключам, дальше тоже несложно.

```
((juxt :a :c) {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}) ; => [1 3]
```

Способов много. Пробовать все придётся долго :)

Comment: Если использовать map с ключами из двух слов, то как изменить elements, чтобы он возвращал эту map?

Comment: @VsSekorin получить список элементов вида `[[a b] c]` и поскидывать их в пустой мап [с помощью `into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into), например.

Comment: Сейчас: `(defn create-element [line]
  (let [[f s n] (str/split line #"\s+")]
    [[f s] (Integer/parseInt n)]))`

`(defn elements []
  (let [maps {}]
    (->>
      (file-lines "resources/file")
      (map #(create-element %))
      (into maps))))`

`(defn test-get []
    (get elements ["V" "D"] 0))` 
Repl: `{["V" "D"] 90, ["A" "B"] 100}`, но не находит элемент (test-get возвращает 0).

Comment: `(get {["V" "D"] 90, ["A" "B"] 100} ["V" "D"] 0)` возвращает `90`. Отлаживайте.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать ассоциативный массив где ключом будет [Word1 Word2] а значением то что в number, т.е.:

```
{[Word1 Word2] 0
 [Word3 Word4] 1}
```

Тогда, для его создания вы пишите:

```
(reduce
  (fn [acc line]
    (let [[a b c] (str/split line #"\s+")]
      (assoc acc [a b] c)))
    {}
    (io/reader file-name))
```

Для поиска используете функцию (get map key not-found)

```
(get lines-map [Word1 Word2] 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

для этого есть `keep`:

```
(defn process [words maps]
  (keep #(if (= words ((juxt :first :second) %))
           %
           (assoc % :number 0))
        maps))

(process ["a" "b"]
         [{:first "x" :second "b" :number 1}
          {:first "a" :second "b" :number 101}
          {:first "a" :second "y" :number 21}
          {:first "a" :second "b" :number 42}])
;;=> ({:first "x", :second "b", :number 0} 
;;    {:first "a", :second "b", :number 101} 
;;    {:first "a", :second "y", :number 0} 
;;    {:first "a", :second "b", :number 42})
```